# Convert numpy array from values to indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array a: [True, False, True, False, False, ...]
And I like to have a numpy array that has the indices of the True and False values, i.e. [0, 2, ...]  and [1, 3, 4, ...]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the indices of the `True` values in `a`, you can use

```
a.nonzero()
```

For the indices of the `False` values, use

```
(~a).nonzero()
```